# Solr Highlight only in fields that have results

Tags: solr, lucene, highlighting

I have a solr query where I search for `(webpage_text:*test* OR company_text:*test*)`

In my highlighting I set my fields to `webpage_text, company_text`. But now I always get BOTH fields in the highlighting result, even when the search term is only found in webpage_text, I also get a highlight result for company_text which is just the full field.

Is it possible to only return the highlights for the fields that had a match ?

I tried requireFieldMatch but that doesn't work.

@EDIT: Might be important information: the 2 fields, are actually empty fields that are filled by copy fields. Does this have an impact ?

```
<field name="company_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" default="" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
<field name="webpage_text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" default="" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>

<dynamicField name="*company_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*talent_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="company_*" dest="company_text" maxLength="30000000"/>
<copyField source="webpage_*" dest="webpage_text" maxLength="30000000"/>
```

@EDIT2: It appears that the copyfields ALWAYS appear in the highlight, even if they have no matches.

Comment: Have you checked this out: http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `requireFieldMatch` option is what you need to use. However, for this to work, you will need to also enable `usePhraseHighlighter` and then make sure you are doing PhraseQueries by wrapping your terms in quotes. (eg. `webpage_text:"*test*"`)

So an example might be the following:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/q=webpage_text%3A"*test*"+OR
  +company_text%3A"*test*"&wt=xml&hl=true&hl.fl=webpage_text%2Ccompany_text
  &hl.simple.pre=<em>&hl.simple.post=<%2Fem>
  &hl.requireFieldMatch=true&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true
```

You will need to adjust the server settings as needed and additional parameters for your scenario.

Comment: I did this, but still it always gives me back the 2 fields. Even if only 1 field has a result. The second field is then just the complete field without highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Solr always returns ALL fields if not specified otherwise. It does not matter whether the field is included in the search query. Fields with a match are highlighted.

If you have only two field, so these two/all fields are returned and one of them is highlighted.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I indeed have 2 fields, but when I do a search, the 2 fields are ALWAYS returned in the highlight, even if one of the 2 doesn't have a match.  I am trying some things out, and I am getting the feeling it has something to do with the fact they are copyfields.

Comment: I see. Is the second field also returned in highlight when only one field is included in the query?

Comment: Yes, If I put company_text as search field, and "company_text, webpage_text" as HL fields, Both fields are returned in the highlighting